# how to do user authentication if user and admin is in a single collection in mongoose in nodejs express? does aggregation work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

this is my schema

```
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');

const adminSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,

    password:String,
    user:[{
        name:String,
        email:String,
        password:String
    }
    ]

})

var user = mongoose.model("Admin",adminSchema)
module.exports = user
;
```

admin login works properly
the problem is
admin can (its available outside as per the schema ) login as user and user is not able to login(cuz its inside as an array )
here is my data base collection:

```
> db.admins.find().pretty()    
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("62ad807e5c40fa9cdd5fb584"),
        "name" : "admin",
        "password" : "$2b$10$wJLM8sXoRbFjFlK6jyjEb.a6n60SlckVBfG1wbDd4A/0e5UOAABGC",
        "__v" : 0,
        "user" : [
                {
                        "name" : "jghuter",
                        "email" : "wehr@jkn.com",
                        "password" : "$2b$10$m3sna5erYQ4RJ95WIqP6MeAHvbTTfrsKn4F7y7yPpZoxvYcRltsba",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("62ad9d0c3b127dc669f423c7")
                }]}
```

this is my login comparison

```
doLogin : (userData)=>{
        return new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
            let loginStatus = false
            let response = {}
            let user = await admin.aggregate([
    {$match: {'user.email': userData.email}},
    {$project: {
        user: {$filter: {
            input: '$user',
            as: 'user',
            cond: {$eq: ['$$user.email', userData.email]}
        }},
        _id: 0
    }}
])
```

if(user){

```
            bcrypt.compare(userData.password,user.password).then((status)=>{
                if (status){
                    console.log('login success');
                   
                    response.user = user
                    response.status = true
                  
                    resolve(response)

                }else
                console.log('login failed');
               resolve({status:false})

            })
        }else{
            console.log('login failed');
            resolve({status:false})
        }

    })
}
```

how to compare it with the result

Comment: is there any particular reason for keeping user's array inside admin?

Comment: yes as per the rules for project it should be inside a single collection (admin,user), is there any other ways to separate a user and admin

Comment: one way to do it is having separate collections for admins and users, and keeping a reference of admin in user document as a relation

Comment: but as per my project rules I cant create two

Comment: heard that aggregation will work but don't know which method to use

Comment: There shouldn't be a separate `admins` collection. That's kind of weird. The normal way to do this is that there is only a `users` collection but there are different **"types"** of users (usually called "roles"). A user with an admin role should be able to use APIs reserved for admins but non-admin users should get an error if they try to use such an API. In the front-end return the user's **role** so that the UI can render the appropriate components depending on user role

Comment: yeah  giving role is good method but don't know how to do and cant   find any good blogs or docs on these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the user's array like this

```
let admins = await db.admins.aggregate([
    {$match: {'user.email': 'wehr@jkn.com'}},
    {$project: {
        user: {$filter: {
            input: '$user',
            as: 'user',
            cond: {$eq: ['$$user.email', 'wehr@jkn.com']}
        }},
        _id: 0
    }}
])
```

it will return something like

```
[ 
    {
        "user" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "jghuter",
                "email" : "wehr@jkn.com",
                "password" : "$2b$10$m3sna5erYQ4RJ95WIqP6MeAHvbTTfrsKn4F7y7yPpZoxvYcRltsba",
                "_id" : ObjectId("62ad9d0c3b127dc669f423c7")
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

comparing password

```
if(admins.length){
  const users = admins[0]?.user;
  if(users.length){
    const user = users[0];
    bcrypt.compare(input.password,user.password);
  }
}
```

Comment: how this works in comparing email and pass in dologin

Comment: as your password is hashed, you cannot compare it directly in query. After query result like above, compare the password field with the input one by bcrypt method

Comment: if(user){

                bcrypt.compare( admin.aggregate([
                    {$match: {'user.email': userData.email}},
                    {$project: {
                        user: {$filter: {
                            input: '$user',
                            as: 'user',
                            cond: {$eq: ['$$user.password', userData.password]}
                        }},
                        _id: 0
                    }}
                ])).then((status)=>{
             does this work , the output is an object so how can we compare them

Comment: updated answer. check it out

Comment: seems like its not woorking

Comment: if(users.length){
           ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Comment: can you share your code repo so that I may know the whole flow of it

Comment: https://github.com/rishamm/do-login

Comment: I can't see the updated code. Also, can you share the query result

Comment: Is there any other way to talk to you

Comment: add me on skype `usamamasood01`

Comment: okay ill be there

Comment: i have sent you a request